# Как удалить элементы из массива по условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, numpy

Есть массив со значениями от -1 до 1.
Как удалить элементы массива по условию, например:
если значение элемента массива больше 0,2 и меньше -0,2?
Наиболее эффективный, быстрый и правильный способ?

```
np.random.seed(31415)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(10, 5)), columns=list("abcde"))
df_corr = df.corr()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так:

```
print(df_corr[(df_corr >= -0.2) & (df_corr <= 0.2)])
```

Вывод:

```
          a         b         c         d         e
a       NaN       NaN       NaN -0.000653  0.076438
b       NaN       NaN -0.096274 -0.088437       NaN
c       NaN -0.096274       NaN -0.184259 -0.035054
d -0.000653 -0.088437 -0.184259       NaN       NaN
e  0.076438       NaN -0.035054       NaN       NaN
```

Только непонятно, что вы имеете в виду под "удалить". У вас матрица. Вы хотите поменять на `NaN` как у меня сделано, удалить строки с неподходящими значениями или может столбцы?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.
Интересует именно удаление ячеек с ненужными значениями.
Я так понимаю, Ваш способ может также подходить, просто создается новая матрица и удаляются NaN? Или я неправ? Или есть более простой способ?

Comment: можно чуточку сократить: `df_corr[df_corr.abs().le(0.2)]` ;)

Comment: @Xsandr21, в Numpy & Pandas невозможно физически удалить ячейку - для этого обычно используют значение `NaN`

Comment: @Xsandr21 Каких ячеек удаление - строк, столбцов? Если удалить все строки и все столбцы, где есть `NaN`, то от матрицы ничего не останется в данном случае. А если вы хотите сдвинуть ячейки на место пропуска, то это будет не пойми что и непонятного размера в результате, все строки и столбцы "поедут"

Comment: @MaxU Понял, благодарю за ответ. Думал, что это возможно )

Comment: @MaxU все работает, благодарю!

Comment: @CrazyElf все работает, благодарю!